# Is it wrong that my dryer plug has one L shaped prong?

Tags: electrical, appliances

We have a fairly new dryer and we are in the process of getting kitchen and laundry remodeled.  The electrician put in a three prong outlet with all prongs straight.  The dryer has one of them L shaped, so it won't go.  What does this mean?  Did he put in the wrong outlet, or is our dryer goofy?

[image: 10-50R receptacle]

EDIT: Here's the inside of the outlet.  There exists both ground and white/neutral. The white unused.  It looks to be an easy fix.  Also showing a picture of the dryer.  Ground connection is available.

[image: Current outlet]

[image: Dryer]

Comment: That connector there is the 50A version of the obsolete and dangerous NEMA 10-30 that is on your dryer cord.   This is a mess! What was that electrician thinking?  Was it a real electrician or something the carpenter did?

Comment: A real electrician... he came via the general contractor.

Comment: Can you post photos (with the breaker off) of the inside of the box for the dryer receptacle?

Comment: What ThreePhaseEel says, if you're comfortable doing that... this might be an easy fix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy screwed up.  It's a 30 amp circuit with a 50 amp receptacle.  They offered to fix it next week, but since we'd like to have a dryer, I'll likely swap it myself tomorrow.  I'll post a pic if I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You have an obsolete, dangerous  NEMA 10-50

It's a member of the NEMA 10 family which has been outlawed for 30 years because it has a very dangerous failure mode.  If anything goes wrong with the neutral wire, the chassis of the range/dryer becomes energized!

In a remodel you are required to come up to current Codes.  No electrician would ever install a 10-30 (let alone a 10-50!) as it would be instantly written up by the inspector.

However it should be easy enough to change the recep to NEMA 14-30.  Just get a thing that looks just like that, but is a 14-30 instead.  Here are the three 30A styles.

[image]

The left one is correct for a dryer.

You must change the dryer cord according to the dryer's instructions (search the web).  An essential part of this is removing a "grounding strap" which attaches the dryer chassis to neutral (which was bad).

Comment: The one the electrician installed looks like this: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fusercontent2.hubstatic.com%2F5706819_f520.jpg&f=1&nofb=1.  The dryer plug would work with the middle one in your lineup.

Comment: Well, that's a straight up code violation for a new or remodel installation, as well as being a 50A (& just as obsolete as the middle 30A) receptacle probably on a 30A circuit, or what should be a 30A circuit unless you have a VERY unusual dryer. Your dryer also needs an updated cord as for the left receptacle.

Comment: It's an easy fix IF there is a separate ground wire (or grounded conduit) running to the outlet. I'd bet there isn't and that's why the "electrician" put in the 10-30!

Comment: See pics added to original post.  All required connections look to be available.  I'm off to Home Depot to get a receptacle and new cord.

Comment: @Mastiff Good stuff... that'll lick it!